# Expose Member Data Through Read-only Iterator

Tags: c++, oop, std

I have a class 'MyClass' which contains some data stored in `std::map`s. The standard maps contain pointers to objects, e.g.

```
private:
   std::map<int,Object*> m_data;
```

I want to expose the data to the outside world but I do not want other classes/functions to be able to modify either (i) the map `m_data` or (ii) the objects pointed to by the values in `m_data`. I would like some hypothetical function, say `getDataBegin()` which returns an iterator over the data which has the properties above. For example I want the following *pseudo-code* examples to fail:

```
iterator_type itr = myclass.getDataBegin();
erase(itr); // not allowed because we cannot modify m_data;
itr.second = NULL; // not allowed to change content of m_data (falls under first rule)
itr.second->methodWithSideEffect(); // not allowed because changes content of object pointed to.
```

In short you could say I am after read-only access to some member data. Is this at all possible in a nice way, and if so then how could I go about it?

Comment: There's no free `erase()` function, so as long as you don't expose non-const references to your container, that's nothing to worry about. If you make the mapped type `const Object *`, then nobody can modify the pointees, either. If changing the mapped type isn't an option, maybe something can be done with `transform_iterator` that constifies the pointers.

Comment: The trouble is in my `MyClass` I need `map<int,Object*>` not `map<int,Object* const>` and the compilers (g++/icc) do not seem happy about casting between the two.

Comment: What about `map<int, Object const *>`, though?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try exposing a boost `transform_iterator` wrapped around the map's `const_iterator`. The transform function should be something like

```
[](const pair<int, object*>& x) 
{
    return make_pair(x.first, const_cast<const object*>(x.second));
}
```

Comment: Absolutely no need whatsoever for `const_cast` here.

Comment: @DeadMG What cast would you use then?

Comment: @Ayjay: He might refer to use the `std::pair` ctor where you explicitly have to provide the template arguments. I see no harm in using `const_cast` to _add_ `const`, but I probably would have used `std::pair`, because it feels to me like it's less confusing than using a function template to not have to spell out types and then having to explicitly cast to compensate for that...

Comment: I generally prefer template arguments to be deduced than specified, but I'm not sure I could give much actual logic behind that aside from personal preference. I could certainly live with both ways.

Answer (score 0):

return a const_iterator, const_iterator allows read only access.

```
std::map<int,Object*>::const_iterator const getDataBegin();
```

Comment: 1) `const_iterator` makes the Object pointer `Object* const`, not `const Object*` - you can modify the Object, but not the pointer. 2) Assuming we get hold of the map, we should be able to pass the `const_iterator` to the `erase` method (fixed in C++11).

Comment: Wrong answer, violates rule (ii).